# only returns one column when use the pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

Here is my csv file

```
Country         2010    2011    2012    2013    2014 
Albania         5.5     19.1    6.9     15.4    8
Algeria         18.2    6       8.1     20      9.5
American Samoa  14.1    13.8    3       14.7    2.3
Andorra         16      3       13.6    12.4    8.3
Angola          17.8    9.8     8.8     6.5     5.5
```

my code:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Wing\\Desktop\\TEST.csv',sep='\t')

print(test.head())
print(test.shape)
print(test.columns)
print(test.dtypes)
```

output:

```
the print test.shape command will output (14,1)
the print test.columns command will output(Index(['Country,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014'], dtype='object')
```

so how can I separate them to 6 columns

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Your csv file seems fine:

```
In [ ]: from io import StringIO
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: TESTDATA = StringIO("""Country         2010    2011    2012    2013    2014 
   ...: Albania         5.5     19.1    6.9     15.4    8
   ...: Algeria         18.2    6       8.1     20      9.5
   ...: American Samoa  14.1    13.8    3       14.7    2.3
   ...: Andorra         16      3       13.6    12.4    8.3
   ...: Angola          17.8    9.8     8.8     6.5     5.5""")
   ...: test = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA,sep='\t')
   ...: print(test)
  Country         2010    2011    2012    2013    2014 
0  Albania         5.5     19.1    6.9     15.4    8   
1  Algeria         18.2    6       8.1     20    ...   
2  American Samoa  14.1    13.8    3       14.7  ...   
3  Andorra         16      3       13.6    12.4  ...   
4  Angola          17.8    9.8     8.8     6.5   ...
```

Comment: but if i use print(test.shape) it display(6,1) it mean 6 rows 1 column
so i can not use the print(test['2010']) command,it will output keyerror:'2010',it seems the column name become (Country         2010    2011    2012    2013    2014) not sperate to 6 columns(Country , 2010 , 2011...etc)